# What is the difference between following cases?

Tags: c#, memory, mapping

Code is in C#

**Case 1**

```
var p = new Person();
p = getPerson(p);
```

**Case 2**

```
var p = new Person();
getPerson(p);
```

In above cases, will any case consume extra memory?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `getPerson` just modifies properties of the `Person` and there are 2 different methods one that returns a person and one that is void, there is no appreciable difference in this code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

   // example 1
   var p = new Person();
   p = getPerson1(p);

   // example 2
   var p2 = new Person();
   getPerson2(p2);
}
```

**Example 1**

```
IL_0001: newobj       instance void ConsoleApp8.Person::.ctor()
IL_0006: stloc.0      // p

// [33 10 - 33 28]
IL_0007: ldloc.0      // p
IL_0008: call         class ConsoleApp8.Person ConsoleApp8.Program::getPerson1(class ConsoleApp8.Person)
IL_000d: stloc.0      // p
```

**Example 2**

```
IL_000e: newobj       instance void ConsoleApp8.Person::.ctor()
IL_0013: stloc.1      // p2

// [36 4 - 36 19]
IL_0014: ldloc.1      // p2
IL_0015: call         void ConsoleApp8.Program::getPerson2(class ConsoleApp8.Person)
IL_001a: nop
```

[OpCodes.Stloc Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.stloc?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Pops the current value from the top of the evaluation stack and stores
>   it in a the local variable list at a specified index.

[OpCodes.Nop Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.nop?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Fills space if opcodes are patched. No meaningful operation is
>   performed although a processing cycle can be consumed.

---

In short, worry about other things